# How to access an instance variable inside a Javascript function in Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a form for editing profiles. Rails automatically generates the form id as 'edit_profile_##' where ## is the profile id of the current user(instance variable-@profile_id). I need to use this form id for my javascript functions. Is there a way to get the current user's profile id inside js? Or is there a way I can override the automatic id generation by rails?

Answer (score 9):

you have to send that using function parameter

.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var user_id = <%= @profile_id %>; // for integer
   var user_name = '<%= @profile_name %>'; // for string

   abc(user_id)// this is your function in .js file

</script>
```

.js

```
 function abc(id){
   alert(""+id)
 }
```

Comment: ok thanks. so thats the only way then? i was trying to see if there was a way without passing it in a function call. coz my js function (see below-submitProfileForm) is actually an event handler which needs to be called only when the form is submitted



Event.observe('window','load',function(){
$('edit_profile_##').observe('submit',submitProfileForm);
});

Comment: yes that is the only way you can access instance variable in .js file

Answer (score 1):

Are you using normal *.html.erb views?

Can't you do something like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    user_id = <%= @profile_id %>;
</script>
```

?

Comment: yes i do use html.erb views. So u mean to say i can include this in my html.erb file? but how do i access user_id inside my .js file?

Comment: I have no idea how you have your js files. But you can create methods and then pass the parameter around, or create a global variable (like in my example, though I really would not recommend that).

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have `@user = {'name'=>'steve'}` in the controller

now your html page can render `<p> <%=@user['name']%> </p>`

now lets say you want to be able to access @user in your .js file; add thisThing & data-url to your tag `<p id="thisThing" data-url="<%=@user%>" > <%=@user['name']%> </p>`

in your .js file `var userInfo = $('#thisThing').data('url')`

now you got userInfo in your .js (its in string)